# Web Deploy 3.6 automatic backup not created properly when deploying from VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am using Web Deploy 3.6 to publish a WebApp from Visual Studio to an IIS 8.5 server. I have configured automatic backup on the server side (based on [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups) article), but when I publish my WebApp from VS2015, my backup only contain two files: archive.xml and system.xml.

If I publish the same WebApp directly from the IIS server, the backup is created as expected.

Because Web Deploy has some known Issues and limitations, I checked that there is no problem with the manifest that is automatically created and used by msdeploy to publish my WebApp.

Here is what is inside my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitemanifest>
  <IisApp path="C:\Users\niniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
  <setAcl path="C:\Users\niniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp" setAclResourceType="Directory" />
  <setAcl path="C:\Users\niniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp" setAclUser="anonymousAuthenticationUser" setAclResourceType="Directory" />
</sitemanifest>
```

I tried to publish from another computer, just to be sure that this problem is not related to my computer, I had the same problem.

Any help or thought would be appreciated :)

Comment: I tried to deploy using msdeploy in command line and I discovered that if I use the Web Deploy Agent Service the backup is created properly but if I use the Web Management Service handler it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone is facing the same problem, I had to give read access to the IIS_IUSRS group on the backup folder to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup the backup by extending the WebDeploy package.  This way the server doesn't have to be pre-configured for backups, its just part of the deployment.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/05/19/extending-the-webdeploy-manifest/

**Side note** - We stopped taking backups when we started using WebDeploy exclusively for web app deployments.  Each WebDeploy package becomes the backup for the next deployment. You should evaluate taking additional backups over time and determine if this process continues to be valuable.  At some point, you can hopefully stop.